# from elementary and high school(s)

Tags: singular-vs-plural

(1a) Most of the students in the chess club come from elementary and high school**s**.

(1b) Most of the students in the chess club come from elementary and high school.

(2a) Most of the students he tutors are in elementary and high school**s**.

(2b) Most of the students he tutors are in elementary and high school.

The word, school, is both uncountable and countable. I am not sure whether I should use the singular or plural form.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming that the club members come from several different schools, I would expect the plural.
2. You could use the singular here as it refers to the students' educational level rather than the actual school thy attend.